# running angular version with ng serve display error :error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code, angular-material

[image: try to run the app this error appear]

here is my package.json:

```
{"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
"@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/cdk": "~10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/router": "^10.2.5",
"@devexpress/analytics-core": "^19.2.8",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.3",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
"angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
"angular-file-uploader": "^5.0.2",
"angular-notifier": "^8.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"c3": "^0.4.24",
"core-js": "^2.6.11",
"d3": "^4.8.0",
"devexpress-reporting": "^19.2.8",
"devexpress-reporting-angular": "^19.2.8",
"devextreme": "^19.2.8",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.21",
"ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
"ng-zorro-antd": "^9.1.1",
"ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
"ngx-autosize": "^1.8.0",
"ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "6.1.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.10.2",
"os": "^0.1.1",
"pace-js": "^1.0.2",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^8.0.0",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
"rxjs": "^6.5.5",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
"sass": "^1.26.9",
"sweetalert2": "^9.15.2",
"xlsx": "^0.16.9",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.28",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.5",
"@angular/language-service": "^10.2.5",
"@types/c3": "^0.6.4",
"@types/chartist": "^0.9.48",
"@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.17",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.177",
"@types/node": "^8.10.61",
"codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
"install-peers": "^1.0.3",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^5.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "~4.0.8"
}
}

Comment: Can you mention the Node & npm versions you are using?

Comment: node -v : 18 , npm :'6.14.17

Answer (score 1):

Node v18 is not gonna work. For Angular v10 you need to to run node version ~12 [check out the documentation.](https://angular.io/guide/versions) in my experience you can go max upto v14.x .

Try this, delete node_modules and package-lock.json. Drop down to Node 12.x <= version <= 14.x and then reinstall the dependencies.

Incase you are still getting errors while starting the server, just investigate the other libraries that you're using and update their version compatible to the Node & npm versions you are using.

Comment: i did what you mentioned but my problem is to update mg angular app from version 8 to 13 when i reached v10 i got this error , so i started with  node version 10 then update it now to version 18 ad try to upgrade the whole app to 9 ,10. ... till v13

Comment: Jumping multiple major versions is a tricky task, along with the necessary code changes you also need to update the other libraries being used. Ideally what we do is to upgrade to a major version and test it out thoroughly before moving to the next one.